# Camel-file read only first line

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I'm using camel-ftp to get a file from a remote server. When the file is moved I need to read the first line which is a header and set the camel headers with it for the rest of the route. Do I need to build a custom processor for it? Was thinking of .split() but that parses every line in the file (which is huge).

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt functionality for that.
You can do something like this:

```
.split(body(String.class).tokenize("\n"))
.when(simple("${header.CamelSplitIndex} == '0'"))
 .doSomething
.otherwise()
 .stop()
```

Comment: It works, but it still goes through every single line in the file. I ended up making a processor with a linereader.